# Apply styles to specific v-for element

Tags: javascript, css, list, vue.js, html-framework-7

I'm making a simple todo list app, and wondering on how to apply styles on **only** specific dynamic `v-for` elements.

```html
<f7-list-item v-for="(listItem, index) in activeList.listItems" :key="index" :class="(checked) ? 'checked':'not-checked'">
 {{ index+1 }}. {{ listItem }}
  <span @click="checkTaskDone(index)">
    <i class="f7-icons" id="check-task-btn">check_round</i>
  </span>
</f7-list-item>
```

```js
export default {
 data() {
  return {
   checked: false
  }
 },
 methods: {
  checkTaskDone(item) {
   if (this.checked == false) {
    this.checked = true;
   } else if (this.checked == true) {
    this.checked = false;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```css
.checked {
 text-decoration: line-through;
 color: #444;
}
```

With this code it adds the class to every single `v-for` list element regardless of which one is clicked, as expected. I'm wondering what's the best approach to deal with this. I've experimented with making a prop from the `index` and trying to target that to apply the styles but I couldn't make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you want to have a "done" or "checked" flag on the individual to-do items, something like:

```
const todoList = [
  {
    name: 'Grab some food',
    done: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Start coding',
    done: false
  }
];
```

And in Vue.js, you could do the class toggling with [`v-bind:class`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) rather than ternary operator:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //checked: false,
      
      activeList: {
        listItems: [
          {
            name: 'Grab some food',
            done: false
          },
          {
            name: 'Start coding',
            done: false
          }
        ]  
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkTaskDone(item) {
      //if (this.checked == false) {
      //  this.checked = true;
      //} 
      //else if (this.checked == true) {
      //  this.checked = false;
      //}
      
      // Check/uncheck
      item.done = !item.done;
    }
  }
}
```

```vue
<f7-list-item 
  v-for="(listItem, index) in activeList.listItems" 
  :key="index"
  :class="{ 'checked': listItem.done }">
  
 {{ index + 1 }}. {{ listItem }}
 
  <span @click="checkTaskDone(listItem)">
    <i class="f7-icons" :id="`check-task-btn${index}`">check_round</i>
  </span>
</f7-list-item>
```

BTW, I'm appending an index on the individual `i.f7-icons` elements because ID should be unique, otherwise please use `class` instead.

Comment: Very easy - thank you so much! Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create dynamic checked array according to `activeList.listItems` length ! Then you can check with index and you can update array data by `this.$set(array,index,value)` ...

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {
   checked: [],
   activeList : {listItems:[1,2,3,5]}
 },
 created: function() {
   for(var i = 0; i < this.activeList.listItems.length; i++) {
     this.checked.push(false);
   }
 },
 methods: {
  checkTaskDone(item) {
   if (this.checked[item] == false) {
    this.$set(this.checked,item, true);
   } else if (this.checked[item] == true) {
    this.$set(this.checked,item, false);
   }
  }
 }
 });
```

```css
.checked {
 text-decoration: line-through;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(listItem, index) in activeList.listItems" :key="index" :class="{checked: checked[index]}">
 {{ index+1 }}. {{ listItem }}
  <span @click="checkTaskDone(index)">
    <i class="f7-icons" id="check-task-btn">check_round</i>
  </span>
</div>

</div>
```